# Getting InvalidJarIndexException when executing python script using jython

Tags: java, apache-axis, rampart, jython-2.5

I am getting a `sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException` when invoking a python script from a web service using jython. I am using JDK 7, Axis2 1.6, rampart 1.6 and jython 2.5.0.

It works fine if same operations are performed from a Servlet or web services with Axis2 1.5 and rampart 1.5.

I am calling jython from the web services to execute a python script.

### refresh.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import subprocess

print "refresh script"
```

### Excerpt from web service method to invoke python script

```
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter();
interp.execfile("/root/Documents/refresh.py");
```

once `execfile()` called, it gives below error

> File "/root/Documents/refresh.py", line 2, in 
>       import os   File "/root/Documents/tomcat/webapps/refresh/WEB-INF/lib/jython.jar/Lib/os.py",
>   line 48, in  sun.misc.InvalidJarIndexException: Invalid index

line 48 in os.py is actually importing java classes from jython.jar. I have also tried importing threading , it fails at line 5 where it again referrers to java classes from jython.jar.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this problem.

Created a Servlet that will make Jython call from init() method. Configured this Servlet to load on startup.

Once the web application is deployed and all the web services are loaded, Servlet would have loaded all the required jython class and it will be reused for subsequent web service calls.